# dropdown for country, city, state with zip code

Tags: drop-down-menu

i want to include country, city, state and zip code for some e-commerce site and i want it as:
if i select specfic country cities of that specific country only is listed. once city is selected states of that city is seen in drop down and once city is seleceted zip code for that city is seen in dropdown.
i searched in google but can't find any reliable link. anyone can help me with link or suggesstions. any help is welcome. thank you
my current code:

```
<form class="clearboth" name="form" action="" method="post" onSubmit="return sign_up(this);">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="<?php echo $_GET['action']?>" />
     <h1>New User: Sign Up</h1>
               <ul class="input_field">
               <li><label>Username <span>*</span></label>
                <input name="username" class="input_textarea" id="username" size="25" req="1" valimessage="Username cannot be blank" 
                      valiclass="required" />
                        </li>   
               <li><label>First Name <span>*</span></label>
                   <input name="first_name" class="input_textarea" id="first_name" size="25" req="1" 
                      valimessage="First name cannot be blank" 
                      valiclass="required" />
                 </li>
               <li><label>Last Name <span>*</span></label>
                 <input name="last_name" class="input_textarea" id="last_name" size="25" req="1" valimessage="Last name cannot be blank" 
                      valiclass="required" />
                </li>
                   <li><label>Street address <span>*</span></label>
                    <input name="address1" class="input_textarea" id="address1" size="25" req="1" valimessage="Street Address cannot be blank" 
                      valiclass="required" />
                      </li>
                 <li><label>Street address 2</label>
                 <input name="address2" class="input_textarea" id="address2" size="25" />
                  </li>
                   <li><label>City <span>*</span></label>
                           <input name="city" class="input_textarea" id="city" size="25" req="1" valimessage="City cannot be blank" 
                      valiclass="required" />
                   </li>
                    <li><label>Country <span>*</span></label>
                          <select name="country" class="input_textarea">
                                <option 
                        value="NA">Please Select</option>
                                <option>Afghanistan</option>
                                <option>Albania</option>
                                <option>Algeria</option>
                                <option>American Samoa</option>
                                <option>Andorra</option>
                                <option>Angola</option>
                                <option>Anguilla</option>
                                <option>Antarctica</option>
                                <option>Antigua and Barbuda</option>
                                <option>Argentina</option>
                                <option>Armenia</option>
                                <option>Aruba</option>
                                <option>Australia</option>
                                <option>Austria</option>
                                <option>Azerbaijan</option>
                                <option>Bahamas</option>
                                <option>Bahrain</option>
                                <option>Bangladesh</option>
                                <option>Barbados</option>
                                <option>Belarus</option>
                                <option>Belgium</option>
                                <option>Belize</option>
                                <option>Benin</option>
                                <option>Bermuda</option>
                                <option>Bhutan</option>
                                <option>Bolivia</option>
                                <option>Bosnia and Herzegowina</option>
                                <option>Botswana</option>
                                <option>Bouvet Island</option>
                                <option>Brazil</option>
                                <option>British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
                                <option>Brunei Darussalam</option>
                                <option>Bulgaria</option>
                                <option>Burkina Faso</option>
                                <option>Burundi</option>
                                <option>Cambodia</option>
                                <option>Cameroon</option>
                                <option>Canada</option>
                                <option>Cape Verde</option>
                                <option>Cayman Islands</option>
                                <option>Central African Republic</option>
                                <option>Chad</option>
                                <option>Chile</option>
                                <option>China</option>
                                <option>Christmas Island</option>
                                <option>Cocos (Keeling)Islands</option>
                                <option>Colombia</option>
                                <option>Comoros</option>
                                <option>Congo</option>
                                <option>Cook Islands</option>
                                <option>Costa Rica</option>
                                <option>Cote D'Ivoire</option>
                                <option>Croatia</option>
                                <option>Cuba</option>
                                <option>Cyprus</option>
                                <option>Czech 
                                  Republic</option>
                                <option>Denmark</option>
                                <option>Djibouti</option>
                                <option>Dominica</option>
                                <option>Dominican 
                                  Republic</option>
                                <option>East Timor</option>
                                <option>Ecuador</option>
                                <option>Egypt</option>
                                <option>El Salvador</option>
                                <option>Equatorial 
                                  Guinea</option>
                                <option>Eritrea</option>
                                <option>Estonia</option>
                                <option>Ethiopia</option>
                                <option>Falkland 
                                  Islands (Malvinas)</option>
                                <option>Faroe 
                                  Islands</option>
                                <option>Fiji</option>
                                <option>Finland</option>
                                <option>France</option>
                                <option>France, Metropolitan</option>
                                <option>French Guiana</option>
                                <option>French 
                                  Polynesia</option>
                                <option>French Southern 
                                  Territories</option>
                                <option>Gabon</option>
                                <option>Gambia</option>
                                <option>Georgia</option>
                                <option>Germany</option>
                                <option>Ghana</option>
                                <option>Gibraltar</option>
                                <option>Greece</option>
                                <option>Greenland</option>
                                <option>Grenada</option>
                                <option>Guadeloupe</option>
                                <option>Guam</option>
                                <option>Guatemala</option>
                                <option>Guinea</option>
                                <option>Guinea-bissau</option>
                                <option>Guyana</option>
                                <option>Haiti</option>
                                <option>Heard and Mc Donald Islands</option>
                                <option>Honduras</option>
                                <option>Hong 
                                  Kong</option>
                                <option>Hungary</option>
                                <option>Iceland</option>
                                <option>India</option>
                                <option>Indonesia</option>
                                <option>Iran (Islamic 
                                  Republic of)</option>
                                <option>Iraq</option>
                                <option>Ireland</option>
                                <option>Israel</option>
                                <option>Italy</option>
                                <option>Jamaica</option>
                                <option>Japan</option>
                                <option>Jordan</option>
                                <option>Kazakhstan</option>
                                <option>Kenya</option>
                                <option>Kiribati</option>
                                <option>Korea, Democratic People's Republic 
                                  of</option>
                                <option>Korea, Republic of</option>
                                <option>Kuwait</option>
                                <option>Kyrgyzstan</option>
                                <option>Lao People's 
                                  Democratic Republic</option>
                                <option>Latvia</option>
                                <option>Lebanon</option>
                                <option>Lesotho</option>
                                <option>Liberia</option>
                                <option>Libyan Arab 
                                  Jamahiriya</option>
                                <option>Liechtenstein</option>
                                <option>Lithuania</option>
                                <option>Luxembourg</option>
                                <option>Macau</option>
                                <option>Macedonia, The 
                                  Former Yugoslav Republic of</option>
                                <option>Madagascar</option>
                                <option>Malawi</option>
                                <option>Malaysia</option>
                                <option>Maldives</option>
                                <option>Mali</option>
                                <option>Malta</option>
                                <option>Marshall 
                                  Islands</option>
                                <option>Martinique</option>
                                <option>Mauritania</option>
                                <option>Mauritius</option>
                                <option>Mayotte</option>
                                <option>Mexico</option>
                                <option>Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
                                <option>Moldova, Republic of</option>
                                <option>Monaco</option>
                                <option>Mongolia</option>
                                <option>Montserrat</option>
                                <option>Morocco</option>
                                <option>Mozambique</option>
                                <option>Myanmar</option>
                                <option>Namibia</option>
                                <option>Nauru</option>
                                <option>Nepal</option>
                                <option>Netherlands</option>
                                <option>Netherlands 
                                  Antilles</option>
                                <option>New Caledonia</option>
                                <option>New Zealand</option>
                                <option>Nicaragua</option>
                                <option>Niger</option>
                                <option>Nigeria</option>
                                <option>Niue</option>
                                <option>Norfolk 
                                  Island</option>
                                <option>Northern Mariana 
                                  Islands</option>
                                <option>Norway</option>
                                <option>Oman</option>
                                <option>Pakistan</option>
                                <option>Palau</option>
                                <option>Panama</option>
                                <option>Papua New Guinea</option>
                                <option>Paraguay</option>
                                <option>Peru</option>
                                <option>Philippines</option>
                                <option>Pitcairn</option>
                                <option>Poland</option>
                                <option>Portugal</option>
                                <option>Puerto 
                                  Rico</option>
                                <option>Qatar</option>
                                <option>Reunion</option>
                                <option>Romania</option>
                                <option>Russian 
                                  Federation</option>
                                <option>Rwanda</option>
                                <option>Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
                                <option>Saint Lucia</option>
                                <option>Saint 
                                  Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
                                <option>Samoa</option>
                                <option>San 
                                  Marino</option>
                                <option>Sao Tome and 
                                  Principe</option>
                                <option>Saudi Arabia</option>
                                <option>Senegal</option>
                                <option>Seychelles</option>
                                <option>Sierra 
                                  Leone</option>
                                <option>Singapore</option>
                                <option>Slovakia (Slovak Republic)</option>
                                <option>Slovenia</option>
                                <option>Solomon 
                                  Islands</option>
                                <option>Somalia</option>
                                <option>South Africa</option>
                                <option>South 
                                  Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
                                <option>Spain</option>
                                <option>Sri 
                                  Lanka</option>
                                <option>St. Helena</option>
                                <option>St. Pierre and Miquelon</option>
                                <option>Sudan</option>
                                <option>Suriname</option>
                                <option>Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands</option>
                                <option>Swaziland</option>
                                <option>Sweden</option>
                                <option>Switzerland</option>
                                <option>Syrian Arab 
                                  Republic</option>
                                <option>Taiwan, Province of 
                                  China</option>
                                <option>Tajikistan</option>
                                <option>Tanzania, United Republic of</option>
                                <option>Thailand</option>
                                <option>Togo</option>
                                <option>Tokelau</option>
                                <option>Tonga</option>
                                <option>Trinidad and Tobago</option>
                                <option>Tunisia</option>
                                <option>Turkey</option>
                                <option>Turkmenistan</option>
                                <option>Turks and 
                                  Caicos Islands</option>
                                <option>Tuvalu</option>
                                <option>Uganda</option>
                                <option>Ukraine</option>
                                <option>United Arab Emirates</option>
                                <option>United Kingdom</option>
                                <option 
                        selected="selected">United States</option>
                                <option>United 
                                  States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
                                <option>Uruguay</option>
                                <option>Uzbekistan</option>
                                <option>Vanuatu</option>
                                <option>Vatican City 
                                  State (Holy See)</option>
                                <option>Venezuela</option>
                                <option>Viet 
                                  Nam</option>
                                <option>Virgin Islands 
                                  (British)</option>
                                <option>Virgin Islands 
                                  (U.S.)</option>
                                <option>Wallis and Futuna 
                                  Islands</option>
                                <option>Western Sahara</option>
                                <option>Yemen</option>
                                <option>Yugoslavia</option>
                                <option>Zaire</option>
                                <option>Zambia</option>
                                <option>Zimbabwe</option>
                            </select>
                    </li>
                   <li><label>State <span>*</span></label>
                    <select name="us_state" class="input_textarea">
                                <option value="NA" 
                        selected="selected">Please Select</option>
                                <option>Alabama</option>
                                <option>Alaska</option>
                                <option>American Samoa</option>
                                <option>Arizona</option>
                                <option>Arkansas</option>
                                <option>Armed Forces 
                                  Africa</option>
                                <option>Armed Forces 
                                  Americas</option>
                                <option>Armed Forces 
                                  Canada</option>
                                <option>Armed Forces 
                                  Europe</option>
                                <option>Armed Forces Middle 
                                  East</option>
                                <option>Armed Forces 
                                  Pacific</option>
                                <option>California</option>
                                <option>Colorado</option>
                                <option>Connecticut</option>
                                <option>Delaware</option>
                                <option>District of 
                                  Columbia</option>
                                <option>Federated States Of 
                                  Micronesia</option>
                                <option>Florida</option>
                                <option>Georgia</option>
                                <option>Guam</option>
                                <option>Hawaii</option>
                                <option>Idaho</option>
                                <option>Illinois</option>
                                <option>Indiana</option>
                                <option>Iowa</option>
                                <option>Kansas</option>
                                <option>Kentucky</option>
                                <option>Louisiana</option>
                                <option>Maine</option>
                                <option>Marshall 
                                  Islands</option>
                                <option>Maryland</option>
                                <option>Massachusetts</option>
                                <option>Michigan</option>
                                <option>Minnesota</option>
                                <option>Mississippi</option>
                                <option>Missouri</option>
                                <option>Montana</option>
                                <option>Nebraska</option>
                                <option>Nevada</option>
                                <option>New 
                                  Hampshire</option>
                                <option>New Jersey</option>
                                <option>New Mexico</option>
                                <option>New 
                                  York</option>
                                <option>North Carolina</option>
                                <option>North Dakota</option>
                                <option>Northern 
                                  Mariana Islands</option>
                                <option>Ohio</option>
                                <option>Oklahoma</option>
                                <option>Oregon</option>
                                <option>Palau</option>
                                <option>Pennsylvania</option>
                                <option>Puerto 
                                  Rico</option>
                                <option>Rhode Island</option>
                                <option>South Carolina</option>
                                <option>South 
                                  Dakota</option>
                                <option>Tenessee</option>
                                <option>Texas</option>
                                <option>Utah</option>
                                <option>Vermont</option>
                                <option>Virgin 
                                  Islands</option>
                                <option>Virginia</option>
                                <option>Washington</option>
                                <option>West 
                                  Virginia</option>
                                <option>Wisconsin</option>
                                <option>Wyoming</option>
                            </select>
                   </li>         

                         <li><label>Zip Code <span>*</span></label>
                    <input name="zip" class="input_textarea" id="zip" size="25" req="1" 
                      valimessage="Invalid Zip code" 
                  valiclass="zip" />
                  </li>
                   <li><label>Phone</label>
                      <input name="phone" class="input_textarea" id="phone" size="25" />
                   </li>
                    <li><label>Fax</label>
                   <input name="fax" class="input_textarea" id="fax" size="25" />
                 </li>
                           <li><label>Email address<span>*</span></label>
                      <input name="email" class="input_textarea" id="email" size="25" req="1" 
                      valimessage="Invalid email address" 
                      valiclass="email" />
                 </li>
                           <li><label>Password <span>*</span></label>
                         <input name="password" type="password" class="input_textarea" id="password" size="25" req="4" 
                      valimessage="not sufficent password lenghth" 
                      valiclass="required" />
                      </li>
                           <li><label>Verify Password</label>
                           <input name="password2" type="password" class="input_textarea" id="password2" size="25" />
                        </li>
                        <li><label>&nbsp;</label>* indicates required fields.</li>

                          <li><label>&nbsp;</label>
                          <input type="submit" value="Sign up" name="btn_signup"  class="red_btn"/>
                          </li>
                          </ul>
```

Comment: Something similar is done here: http://triaslama.wordpress.com/2008/04/01/dynamic-dropdownlist-just-fill-it-with-array/

Answer (score 0):

I just did that things you said in Magento 1.7.0.2, But I didn't do it as extension, seems like dirty way.

I just do it for AU, Here is what I do: 
1. find your billing.phtml in \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml
or in \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\persistent\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml
at these code in the bottom:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
CountryListener();
jQuery('#billing\\:country_id').change(function() {
CountryListener();
});     
});

var OriginalBillingCity = '<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getCity()); ?>';
var OriginalBillingPostcode = '<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getPostcode()); ?>';
function CountryListener()
{
var selectVal = jQuery('#billing\\:country_id option:selected').val();
if(selectVal == "AU"){
jQuery('#billing\\:region_id').change(function() {      ////add select change listener          
StateToCityList();
});
jQuery("#billing\\:city")
.replaceWith('<select id="billing:city" name="billing[city]" class="required-entry"><option value="">Select the State first, then you have options</option></select>');
jQuery("#billing\\:postcode")
.replaceWith('<select id="billing:postcode" name="billing[postcode]"><option value="">Please select the City first</option></select>');
}else{
jQuery("#billing\\:city")
.replaceWith('<input type="text" class="input-text required-entry absolute-advice" title="City" value="' + OriginalBillingCity + '" id="billing:city" name="billing[city]" autocomplete="off">');
jQuery("#billing\\:postcode")
.replaceWith('<input type="text" class="input-text required-entry absolute-advice" title="postcode" value="' + OriginalBillingPostcode + '" id="billing:postcode" name="billing[postcode]" autocomplete="off">');
} 
}

var state_city = [];
<?php echo $this->getCityList(); ?>
var city_postcode = [];
<?php echo $this->getPostCodeList(); ?>
//state_city.push({state:'New South Wales',city:'CHATSWORTH'});
//state_city.push({state:'New South Wales',city:'NAUGHTONS GAP',postcode:2470});
//state_city.push({state:'Queensland',city:'TERRICA',postcode:4387});

function StateToCityList(){
var StateText = jQuery('#billing\\:region_id option:selected').text();
if(StateText == "Please select region, state or province")
{   jQuery("#billing\\:city")
.replaceWith('<select id="billing:city" name="billing[city]" class="required-entry"><option value="">Select the State first, then you have options</option></select>');
} else{                             
/////////cookie////////         
/*var cookie_name = "billingstate";         
Mage.Cookies.clear(cookie_name);
Mage.Cookies.set(cookie_name, StateText);           
alert(Mage.Cookies.get(cookie_name));*/
//////////////////////////          
var CityList =  '<select id="billing:city" name="billing[city]" class="required-entry">'+
'<option>Select the City You live</option>';
for(i=0;i<state_city.length;i++)
{
if(state_city[i].state == StateText)
CityList += '<option value="'+state_city[i].city+'">'+state_city[i].city+'</option>';
}
CityList += '</select>';

jQuery("#billing\\:city")
.replaceWith(CityList);     
jQuery('#billing\\:city').change(function() {       ////add select change listener      
CityToPostcode();
});         
}
}   

function CityToPostcode(){      
var CityVal = jQuery('#billing\\:city option:selected').val();
var StateText = jQuery('#billing\\:region_id option:selected').text();
if(StateText == "Please select region, state or province" && CityVal == "Select the City You live")
{   jQuery("#billing\\:postcode")
.replaceWith('<select id="billing\\:postcode" name="billing[postcode]"><option value="">Please select the City first</option></select>');
} else{         
var PostcodeList =  '<select id="billing:postcode" name="billing[postcode]" >';
for(i=0;i<city_postcode.length;i++)
{
if(city_postcode[i].state == StateText && city_postcode[i].city == CityVal)
PostcodeList += '<option value="'+city_postcode[i].postcode+'">'+city_postcode[i].postcode+'</option>';
}
PostcodeList += '</select>';

jQuery("#billing\\:postcode")
.replaceWith(PostcodeList);     
}
}

</script>
```

Then edit Billing.php in \app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Billing.php
Create two function as below:

```
    public function getCityList(){
require_once '/your server path/example.com/html/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();    
$data = "";
/////////////// call SQL read////////////////
$connection_read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read'); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM state_to_city_AU";
$count = 1;
foreach ($connection_read->fetchAll($sql) as $State_City) {
$data .= 'state_city.push({state:"'.$State_City['state'].'", city:"'.$State_City['city'].'"});';    
}       
return $data;       
}

public function getPostCodeList(){
require_once '/your server path/example.com/html/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();        
$data = "";
/////////////// call SQL read////////////////
$connection_read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');         
$sql = "SELECT * FROM city_to_postcode_AU";
$count = 1;
foreach ($connection_read->fetchAll($sql) as $city_postcode) {
$data .= 'city_postcode.push({state:"'.$city_postcode['state'].'", city:"'.$city_postcode['city'].'", postcode:"'.$city_postcode['postcode'].'"});';            
}       
return $data;       
}
```

At last, you need to prepare to add two database table state_to_city_AU (two column, state and city) and city_to_postcode_AU(three column, state-city-postcode).

You need to do the same way for shipping address code.
It works for me, you can try.